# Remove all the dots but not \in numbers - Java

Tags: java, replace

I am trying to replace all the `.` in a string except numbers like `1.02`

I have a string : -

```
String rM = "51.3L of water is provided. 23.3L is used."
```

If I use `rM.replaceAll()` then every dot will be replaced, I want my string to be : -

```
51.3L of water is provided 23.3L is used
```

Is it possible to do in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replaceAll()` with the right regex can do it for you.

This uses a negative look-ahead and look-behind to look for a '.' not in the middle of a decimal number.

```
rM.replaceAll("(?<![\\d])\\.(?![\\d]+)", "")
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not a java developer but can you try it with a pattern like below.

```
rM = rM.replaceAll("(?<=[a-z\\s])\\.", "");
```

Comment: This would be a much nicer solution but as it stands does not work. I'll see if I can build off this

Comment: @RobEvans Hi Updated can you confirm again

Comment: You got it! `String rM = "51.3L of water is provided. 23.3L is Used.";
        System.out.println(rM.replaceAll("(?<=[a-zA-Z\\s])\\.", ""));` worked perfect.. I made one minor amendment to include capital letters (even though there were none in the input the regex should handle it the same) Output: `51.3L of water is provided 23.3L is Used` (I introduced one capital letter as a test)

Comment: If dose not replace if there are two dots. It just removes 1.

Comment: @XomaDevs try with this `rM = rM.replaceAll("(?<=[a-z\\s])\\.+", "");`

Answer (score 1):

yes its possible. Something like the following should work. The regex should just check that the `element` starts with a character 0-9. If yes, don't change the element. If no, replace any `.` with the empty string.

```java
        String rM = "51.3L of water is provided. 23.3L is used.";
        String[] tokens = rM.split(" ");

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (String element : tokens) {
            if (element.matches("[0-9]+.*")) {
                buffer.append(element + " ");
            } else {
                buffer.append(element.replace(".", "") + " ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(buffer.toString());
```

Output:

```java
51.3L of water is provided 23.3L is used
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple approach that assumes you want to get rid of dots that are placed directly after a `char` which isn't a whitespace.

The following code basically splits the sentence by whitespace(s) and removes trailing dots in every resulting character sequence and joins them afterwards to a single `String` again.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example sentence
    String rM = "51.3L of water is provided. 23.3L is used.";
    // split the sentence by whitespace(s)
    String[] parts = rM.split("\\s+");
    
    // go through all the parts
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        // check if one of the parts ends with a dot
        if (parts[i].endsWith(".")) {
            // if it does, replace that part by itself minus the trailing dot
            parts[i] = parts[i].substring(0, parts[i].length() - 1);
        }
    }
    
    // join the parts to a sentence String again
    String removedUndesiredDots = String.join(" ", parts);
    // and print that
    System.out.println(removedUndesiredDots);
}
```

The output is

```
51.3L of water is provided 23.3L is used
```

Answer (score 1):

Using negative lookahead you can use `\.(?![\d](\.[\d])?)`.

```
private static final String DOTS_NO_NUM_REGEX = "\\.(?![\\d](\\.[\\d])?)";
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(DOTS_NO_NUM_REGEX);

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String s = "51.3L of water is provided. 23.3L is used.";

    String replaced = PATTERN.matcher(s).replaceAll("");
    System.out.println(replaced);
}
```

Output:

```
51.3L of water is provided 23.3L is used
```